# (JAVA) Read user input with out deleteing what they have written when sending System.out

Tags: java, console, newline

This is in a Java command line application. I am trying to make an application that will be constantly receiving data and then printing it. I also need to accept commands to send out the port. Every time I type something it gets moved up a line when the console outputs. Ideally I could have a prompt before the command. I have tried to grab the current input, delete it, then print the msg, and then reprint the input, but I could only grab input after the user pressed enter. I have spent a couple hours just googling trying to find the answer. I also have asked some people I know but still nothing.

I tried

```java
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
  System.out.println(scn.next());
}
```

but it does not fire until I press enter.

Comment: Can you provide some code example(s) of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Ive tried to get data from the line that was not printed using ` Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(scn.next());
        }`
but it does not fire until I press enter.

Ideally i'd like to emulate a minecraft server console like thing

Comment: @azurefrog  tell me what to add it has the error it has the desired behavior if you'd read it

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619867/read-user-input-without-deleteing-what-they-have-written-when-console-output-in ... which is in turn a duplicate.

Comment: Yea because someone closed this one i did not know that people reopened it xd